# Implementing Equal Earth Projection for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I am trying to find a means to implement the new Equal Earth projection (http://shadedrelief.com/ee_proj/) into ArcGIS Desktop (for my contractors to use in our products) - has anyone made progress on this yet and where could I access this?

Comment: Esri is the only organization which can add new projections to ArcGIS. Adding an enhancement request via the [Ideas page](https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/) is a starting-point for such an addition.

Answer (score 2):

We're planning on it being in the next release(s). That is, ArcGIS Desktop and Server 10.7.0 and ArcGIS Pro 2.3. Of course, something very odd could happen and it doesn't make it in, but that's very unlikely at this point.

Disclosure: Esri employee who works with one of the creators of the Equal Earth projection. (He did not think it would take off as it has or he would have gotten it into the software sooner)

Comment: ArcGis Desktop 10.7.0 would be released when? January '19 I assume?

Comment: Release dates are not firm yet.

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS Pro 2.3 released last month includes the Equal Earth projection. See: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/whats-new-in-arcgis-pro.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_45F9A3B9CB89486DBD54C4A68611D8C1